# ajax data isn't the same in chrome vs firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

Some reason I can return data fine from a `POST` in Chrome. The data returned looks like this when using Chrome:

```
{"email":"account@bytestand.com","customer_id":20413,"credit_amount":50.0,"currency_symbol":"$"}
```

But then when the same `POST` is completed on FireFox I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

Somehow the `data` isn't being handled the same and I don't know why.

Here is the code that generates the ajax request

```
function getCustomerAndCredit() {
  console.log("getCustomerAndCredit");
  $(function() {
      $("form[action='" + shopAddress + "/account/login']").submit(function(event){
        console.log("this is past the submit event in Firefox");
        var custEmail = $("form[action='" + shopAddress + "/account/login'] input[type=email]").val();
        var pass = $("form[action='" + shopAddress + "/account/login'] input[type=password]").val();
        sessionStorage.setItem('custEmail', custEmail);
        sessionStorage.setItem('pass', pass);
        sessionStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true);
        debugger;
          $.ajax({
              url: "/apps/proxy/return_customer",
              data: {email: custEmail},
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "js",
              complete: function(data) {
                debugger;
                if(noCustomerInDB(data)){
                  if(data.responseJSON == undefined){
                    sessionStorage.setItem('customer_id', JSON.parse(data.responseText).customer_id);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('creditAmount', JSON.parse(data.responseText).credit_amount);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('currency', JSON.parse(data.responseText).currency_symbol);
                  }
                  else {
                  sessionStorage.setItem('customer_id', data.responseJSON.customer_id);
                  sessionStorage.setItem('creditAmount', data.responseJSON.credit_amount);
                  sessionStorage.setItem('currency', data.responseJSON.currency_symbol);
                  }                  
                }
                // console.log("What is the credit_amount here in getCustomerAndCredit " + sessionStorage.getItem('creditAmount'));
              },
          });
      });
  });  
}
```

And then this is where the `data` is going:

```
function noCustomerInDB(data){
  console.log("this is the todd variable " + data);
  console.log("stringify data " + JSON.stringify(data));
  console.log("what about just data?? " + JSON.parse(data));
  console.log("this is the response down here in the no customer function" + data.responseText);
  if(data.responseText == ""){
    return false;
  }
  else{
    if (JSON.parse(data.responseText).customer_id == "no_customer"){
      sessionStorage.setItem('creditAmount', "null");
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

I did some more digging and now its looking like the `ajax` isn't being called on FireFox. Because the data returned from the `POST` looks like this:

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

Comment: `dataType: js` That isn't valid. I've noticed FF is a bit more strict about the dataType where as Chrome makes more assumptions. Change it to JSON

Comment: ... also aren't you supposed to use JSON.parse on string type ? But it seems like you are returning a JSON ?

Comment: My God I just noticed you are storing a password in the client's session as well as a "loggedIn" flag. Just... don't do that. Anything on the client side can be modified by the user and any malware can inspect data on the client.

Comment: you're right on the security side of things.. And `js` to `JSON` didn't change anything.. shoot

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be - dataType: "js"

Use dataType: "json" instead. Also make sure that "/apps/proxy/return_customer" has the proper header configured to deploy JSON:

"Content-Type: application/json"

Comment: yea, I changed it from `js` to `json` and it didn't make a difference.. arghh.. any other ideas? Oh and yes the returned JSON is valid as it works fine in Chrome..

Comment: Just checking your code better you have if(data.responseJSON == undefined) sessionStorage.setItem('customer_id', JSON.parse(data.responseText).customer_id);

If your response is undefined then you'll be trying to json.parse an undefined object no? It would be strange for this to be the problem since you say it works on chrome but this code might not be right

Can you put an alert like this to debug:

if(data.responseJSON == undefined){
                 alert("undefined")
                  else {
         alert("defined")
}

Maybe Chrome can interpret the JSON and run the 2nd stat

Comment: I added this to the original question.. I did some more digging and now its looking like the `ajax` isn't being called on FireFox. Because the data returned from the `POST` looks like this:

    {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: Starting to make more sense... Try removing dataType: "json" altogether... Most likely it's sending just a string not JSON encoded and Chrome takes care of it while Firefox messes up....